# Use file path from clipboard to open directory in explorer

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to open a file in the windows explorer.

The file directory is stored in a QR Code, after decoding, the path gets copied to the clipboard. From there it needs to be opened in the windows explorer because the QR Decoder doesn't automatically recognize the code as a file path.

Is there a way to process a file path in Powershell and open it in the windows explorer?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a recent version of Powershell then you can just do this:

```
explorer (Get-Clipboard)
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. Can't upvote because of post count. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Prior to PowerShell 5.0 you needed Pscx installed to have the Get-Clipboard cmdlet +1.

Comment: any possible way to open the folder instead of the actual file link in clipboard.. e.g. `c:\tmp\sub1\test.docx`  is in clipboard, and i wish to open `c:\tmp\sub1` folder in explorer instead of the file itself.

Comment: @ihightower try this `Start [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(Get-Clipboard)`

Answer (score 1):

You can open a folder in Windows Explorer via PowerShell like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start(<FolderPath>)
```

Or this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath <FolderPath>
```

This also works for other items, such as URLs, which will open in your default browser.